# Python Selenium in AWS Lambda returns empty HTML

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium

I'm using Python's Selenium lib for crawling and my scripts are Lambdas on AWS.

This is how my config looks like:

```
def get_headless_driver():
    options = Options()
    options.binary_location = '/opt/headless-chromium'
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--single-process')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('--window-size=1920x1080')
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')

    return webdriver.Chrome('/opt/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
```

driver = get_headless_driver()

My script was running for a couple of months and then it stopped, with an error that it can not locate an element:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="x-widget-9"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[8]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody[2]/tr/td[1]/div/div/div[1]').text
```

I have tried to change element (but it seams like it does not find anything). HTML that my driver gets is empty, and it looks like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html>
```

I have tested it locally (on my computer, without AWS Lambdas) and everything works fine.

Do you know what can be an issue?

Answer (score -1):

If you selenium version > 4.3
Then try this:

```
driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="x-widget-9"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[8]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody[2]/tr/td[1]/div/div/div[1]').text
```

[link](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/a4995e2c096239b42c373f26498a6c9bb4f2b3e7/py/CHANGES)

Comment: My driver returns only this "<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html>
"

Comment: they sometimes update/change their code. You need to update your code according to their changes. Let's try inspect element directly online their website

Comment: Code works fine on my machine, everything works good, but it does not work when I add it on AWS